# How to console.log() this function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'd like to generate JSX for React-Native, yet I do want to examine each key/value using `console.log()`.

what I am after:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.types).map((obj) => (
          console.log(obj); <-- This guy
          <Item label={obj[TYPE]} value={obj[ID]} />
          ))}
```

But an Error is thrown "Unexpected token"

How can I still debug my values inside map?

Comment: `(obj) => (` That's not how you do an arrow function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the comma operator:

```
 {Object.keys(this.state.types).map((obj) => (
      console.log(obj), <-- This guy
      <Item label={obj[TYPE]} value={obj[ID]} />
      ))}
```

Which evaluates the statement and then discards it, or you can use the || operator which will evaluate `console.log` which returns `false` and then will return the React element:

```
 {Object.keys(this.state.types).map((obj) => console.log(obj) || (

      <Item label={obj[TYPE]} value={obj[ID]} />
      ))}
```

However, both are fairly hacky, I recommend you turn your arrow function into a multi-line arrow and just use `return`:

```
 {Object.keys(this.state.types).map((obj) => { 
      console.log(obj);
      return <Item label={obj[TYPE]} value={obj[ID]} />
  })}
```

On a side note - don't forget to set the `key` property on your objects returned from an array or you'll get a performance slowdown and a warning (you're currently not doing this).

Answer (score 5):

The round brackets in `=> (` tell the function that it's returning an object (JSX is transpiled into a JS object). You want a function body to run `console.log()`, and then return the `<Item>` element.

Convert the round brackets to curly ones, and add a return statement:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.types).map((obj) => {
  console.log(obj); <-- This guy
  return (
    <Item label={obj[TYPE]} value={obj[ID]} />
  );
})}
```